# How can I change the row's background in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a doubt, I'm still learning WPF.

I'd like to change the background color ina a datagrid depending of a class value. For example:

```
public class Animal
{
     public bool CanFly { get; set; }
}
```

Depending of CanFly value in Animal, must choice if the color is green o red (it's just an example). I'm not sure if I must use a style or a value converter. Which of them is most convenient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`Setter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.aspx) for the default and a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) to change it as necessary, converters are for conversion, not triggering. Use the [`RowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle.aspx) to add those to your rows.

Comment: One question H.B., how can I bind property CanFly in the setter?

Comment: @OscarFimbres: You are not binding it in the `Setter`, you use that to set the `Background` of the row. The binding goes into the `DataTrigger.Binding`. You have two setters, one for the default value and one for the changed value inside the `DataTrigger.Setters` collection.